# Torrent системы: принцип работы

Tags: torrent

Доброго всем времени суток!

Есть некоторый вопрос по торрентам. 
Не совсем понимаю принцип работы этой системы (точнее, принцип-то я понимаю, но именно со следующим вопросом есть непонятка), а именно:
Есть у меня, например, несколько сотен торрент-файлов, скачанных с одного из торрент-трекеров. В случае, если этот торрент-трекер не будет доступен по каким-то причинам (Вам, наверное, уже известно, по каким), есть ли возможность, в случае чего, начать скачивание файлов, которые находятся под этим торрентом?

Я имею ввиду будут ли сами торрент-файлы работать, как и прежде, если сам трекер будет закрыт? Скачивание, ведь, идет, если я не ошибаюсь, по системе P2P?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Трекер «связывает» клиентов друг с
> другом, но напрямую не участвует в
> обмене раздаваемых файлов. Более того,
> трекер не имеет никакой информации об
> этих файлах, поскольку клиенты только
> сообщают ему инфохеш. **Трекер считается
> «слабым» местом системы BitTorrent,
> поскольку при его отключении новые
> клиенты просто не могут друг друга
> «найти». При этом уже участвующие в
> раздаче клиенты могут некоторое время
> продолжать файлообмен, постепенно
> теряя тех, кто отключился или у кого
> поменялся IP-адрес.** Для решения этой
> проблемы могут использоваться
> резервные трекеры или специальные
> бестрекерные протоколы, например [DHT](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DHT).

Википедия: [`BitTorrent`-трекер](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80#.D0.A0.D0.BE.D0.BB.D1.8C_.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.BA.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B0)

Comment: Благодарю. Как я полагаю, DHT должны уже быть задействованы с самого начала и это не решит проблему, в случае отказа трекера, верно?

Comment: В случае отказа трекера пиры начинают искать файлы так: опрашивают всех известных им пиров на предмет наличия у них нужного файла. Если у них этот файл есть, они отсылают положительтный ответ, и начинается скачивание. Если нет, то они рассылают аналогичные запросы списку своих известных пиров. Так поиск идёт по графу пиров пока у кого-то не будет найден искомый файл. Такая структура предполагает, что у каждого пира есть каой-то список адресов пиров. К тому же возникает проблема связности графа: возможно существование обособленных групп пиров, к которым нет доступа извне.